# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта C#

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, linked-list

У меня возникает ошибка

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

в методе `Add()` класса `SortedLinkedList`. Я хочу сравнить элемент любого типа с другим элементом этого же типа, предполагается, что типы будут либо инт, либо дабл, либо строки. Мне пришлось вместо оператора `<` пользоваться методом `CompareTo()`.Поскажите как в моем случае без ошибок можно сравнить данные двух узлов, учитвыая то, что они одного и того же типа. Если пользоваться методом `CompareTo()`, то подскажите как это делать без ошибок.

```
public class Node<D>
{
    public D Data { get; set; }
    public Node(D data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public Node<D> Next { get; set; }

}
public class SortedLinkedList<D> where D: IComparable
{
    Node<D> head; // first element
    Node<D> tail; // last element

    int count = 0;

    public int Count {get { return count; } set { count = value; } }
    public bool IsEmpty() { return count == 0; }

    public void PrintList()
    {
        Node<D> current = head;

        string result = "";

        while (current != null)
        {
            result += current.Data;
            result += ", ";
            current = current.Next;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public void Add(D Data)
    {
        Node<D> node = new Node<D>(Data);
        if (head == null) // if the list is empty
        {
            head = node; // then we're about to fill the first slot.
        }
        else
        {
            Node<D> current = head;
            Node<D> previous = null;

            while (current.Data.CompareTo(node.Data) < 0) 
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            previous.Next = node;
            node.Next = current;    
        }
        count++;
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedLinkedList<int> A = new SortedLinkedList<int>();
        int[] s = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            A.Add(s[i]);
        }
        A.PrintList();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Вам нужно добавить проверку на null в цикле while: `current == null || current.Data...`. Выход по этой проверке произойдет в том случае, если добавляемый элемент является последним.

Comment: на каком строке бросает исключение?подразумиваю что на `previous.Next`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> while (current.Data.CompareTo(node.Data) < 0) 
> {
>      previous = current;
>      current = current.Next;
> }
> ```

В этом цикле у вас `current` может стать равным `null`(если вы добавляете значение в конец списка, то есть добавляете самый "большой" элемент по сравнению с теми, который уже есть в списке) и вы получите эту ошибку. Поэтому вы должны добавить дополнительную проверку на `null` для `current`

```
while (current != null && current.Data.CompareTo(node.Data) < 0) 
{
    previous = current;
    current = current.Next;
}
```